# In .NET how do I convert a nullable int to a double?

Tags: c#, .net

```
subTotal += carts.Amount * product.Price;
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'double'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You need to get the value of the nullable (if it has one).

Comment: You should not be using doubles for monetary code. Use [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx).

Comment: An explicit conversion exists. Did you forget to include a cast in your expression? It really is not clear what you're asking. There are lots of answers on Stack Overflow already discussing converting from `int` to `double` and converting from a nullable value to a non-nullable value (see marked duplicate). If you have a question not answered in those many other posts, please explain: provide a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, and describe _specifically_ what it is you've tried and what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
subTotal += carts.Amount * product.Price;
```

you try to implicitly convert an `int?` to an `int` (`carts.Amount`). Solution:

```
if (carts.Amount.HasValue) {
    subTotal += carts.Amount.Value * product.Price;
} else {
    //carts.Amount is null, handle it
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Convert.ToDouble(x)` where x is the int value.  Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayes1wa5(v=vs.110).aspx for more information (this is C#, but its similar in the other Cs)

Answer (score -2):

int? nullableIntVal = 100;
var dblVal = Convert.ToDouble(nullableIntVal.GetValueOrDefault(0));